# An electrostatic problem for two disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ - how can the solution be represented?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, waves, potential, boundary-conditions

The electrostatic Laplace problem for the exterior of a disk can be solved in a straightforward manner using separation of variables. Suppose we have a unit disk $\Omega$ with a charge density of $f$ on the boundary. Then the solution to the exterior problem,
\begin{align}
& \Delta v(x) = 0 \quad \quad  x\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{\Omega}, \\
& v |_{\partial D}(x) = f,
\end{align}
is given through separation of variables as
$$
v(x) = v(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{-n}(a_n \cos(n\theta)+b_n \sin(n\theta)),
$$
where
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta)\cos(n\theta) d\theta, \\
b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta)\sin(n\theta) d\theta.
$$
But what about the case where we have two disks $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, and we want to determine the solution to the exterior Laplace problem for a charge density $f$, with $f$ defined on the union of the disks $D=\Omega_1\cup \Omega_2$? Say for example the disks both have radius $1$ and are symmetric on the $x_1$ axis with a distance of $6$ between them.

Can we just take define two new origins $O_1$ and $O_2$ at the center of the disks, with associated polar coordinates $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2)$, and then say the following:
$$
v(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty r_1^{-n}(a_n \cos(n\theta_1)+b_n \sin(n\theta_1)) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty r_2^{-n}(a_n \cos(n\theta_2)+b_n \sin(n\theta_2)).
$$
Is this a valid solution? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a solution due to the linearity of the Lapacian. If I have 2 charge distributions $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ and

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 v_1 &= \rho_1\\
\nabla^2 v_2 &= \rho_2
\end{align}
then we have that
\begin{align}
\nabla^2 v_1 + \nabla^2 v_2 &= \rho_1 + \rho_2\\
&= \nabla^2( v_1 + v_2)\;.
\end{align}

This is known as the principle of superposition.